How to track transactions for spl tokens
I am a Web 2 developer currently learning about Solana. I prefer learning by doing, so I am building an app but have encountered an issue. I want to calculate the price of tokens available in a user's wallet by listening to token transactions using the onAccountChange WebSocket method. Although it works, the updates are very slow, and it seems to miss some transactions. I need to listen to all transactions and calculate the latest token prices for each swap transaction. While there are many APIs available for this purpose, they are paid, and I lack the resources to use them. Therefore, third-party libraries are not an option.
Here is the code I tried. Currently, it only listens for transactions of one token address ($WEN), but in practice, it will need to listen to all tokens in the user's wallet. Thus, I need multiple listeners for different token transactions.
if (mintAddress === 'WENWENvqqNya429ubCdR81ZmD69brwQaaBYY6p3LCpk') {
          console.log("Starting subscription")
          wssSolanaConnection.onAccountChange(
            new PublicKey(mintAddress),
            async (accountInfo, context) => {
              console.log('Getting pool info for ', mintAddress);
              // console.log(
              //   'DATA FOR ',
              //   LIQUIDITY_STATE_LAYOUT_V4.decode(accountInfo.data),
              // );
              // TODO: Add additional logic to handle data changes
            },
          );
        }

